# Updating variables into sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to update the variables into the sqlite3 database. The query is working in sqlite browser but when I want to update through my web, it gives me 'Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object'.

```
Code:
$DB = new PDO('sqlite:database/Sample.sqlite3');
$No = 1;
$Name = 'John';
$RecordNo = 2;
$statement ="update Sample set No =".$No.", Name='".Name."', Date='2012-05-14' where RecordNo=".$RecordNo;
$update = $DB->prepare($statement);
$update->execute();
```

The fatal error was at the statement of '$update->execute();' where it should execute as there is no syntax errors or code. Kindly advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative...

```
<?php
$DB = new PDO('sqlite:database/Sample.sqlite3');
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of insert values */
$No = 1;
$Name = 'John';
$RecordNo = 2;
$sth = $dbh->prepare('update sample set No=? Name=? Date='2012-05-14' where Recordno =?');
$sth->execute(array($No, $Name,$RecordNo));
?>
```

Comment: thanks it solved my call to member function as object. But why does it happen?

Comment: Without a debugger I'm unable to give you a proper answer, however you may want to check the value of $statement. Also the string literals may have an effect.